# NUnit TestFixture with TestCases

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Does NUnit provide functionality to have `TestCase` attributes associated with a `TestFixture`? I'd like to run the same set of tests on different implementations of the same interface. The concrete implementation would then be chosen in the `SetUp` method, and each test should be run with every implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any possibility for this. But nice idea anyway.

If you are not keen about the `TestCase` atribute you could use the `TestCaseSource` attribute with an abstract base class.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public class TestCases : List<TestCaseData>
    {
        public TestCases()
        {
            Add(new TestCaseData(1));
            Add(new TestCaseData(2));
        }
    }

    public abstract void Test(int i);
}

[TestFixture]
public class B : A
{
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCases))]
    public override void Test(int i)
    {
        Assert.That(i, Is.GreaterThan(0));
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class C : A
{
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCases))]
    public override void Test(int i)
    {
        Assert.That(i, Is.LessThan(10));
    }
}
```